# ComboBox and KeyValuePair List not working correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a ComboBox on a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) form. It is Databound to a column in a TableAdapter and the DataSource is a manually created KeyValuePair List. The problem is that when the form is displayed; the ValueMember is displayed in the ComboBox, not the DisplayMember. If you click the drop down, the Key List Values are displayed. When you make a selection, in the OnValidating method, the SelectedItem is -1.

I believe that the ComboBox is setup correctly. What have I done wrong?

```
this.cboFormat.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.BindingSource, "Format", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

InitializeComponent();

List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> loFormat = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
loFormat.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Format 1"));
loFormat.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Format 2"));
loFormat.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "Format 3"));

this.cboFormat.DataSource = new BindingSource(loFormat, null);
this.cboFormat.DisplayMember = "Value";
this.cboFormat.ValueMember = "Key";
```

---

Problem solved:

I found that if the Column in the DataBinding is an int, but the Value from the List is a string, then the problem above resulted. I changed the Databinding to a view that displayed the text from the lookup table the int tied to. The Key of the List would be the int from the lookup table. If that makes any sense.

```
SELECT DisplayMember FROM LookupTable AS LT INNER JOIN DataTable AS DT ON LT.Id = DT.LookupId.
```

Then the KeyValuePair worked as expected.

Comment: I tried a Dictionary first with the following and I do not have the problem with the SelectedIndex, but the problem with the ValueMember remained the same;            Dictionary<int, string> loFormat = new Dictionary<int, string>
            {
                {1, "Format 1"},
                {2, "Format 2"},
                {3, "Format 3"}
            };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I threw together a window with a ComboBox and a Button.  I don't see what you describe at all.  My code looks something like this:

```
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "Format", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
        List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> loFormat = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        loFormat.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Format 1"));
        loFormat.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Format 2"));
        loFormat.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "Format 3"));
        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(loFormat, null);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
    }

    private void comboBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    }
```

The validating handler has the correct selected item and it initializes just fine.  Maybe it is something else that you haven't show in your code snippet.

Comment: There must be something in my code in other places that I have not found yet. It works fine when the DataSource is a DataTable of some kind.  On a plain blank form, the code works just fine also.  But when I try this on my Inherited forms and ComboBox, I always get the same results, be it with a KeyValuePair or a Dictionary.  I will keep looking.

Comment: @ggrewe1959 Is your ComboBox a derived class or the stock ComboBox?

Comment: It is a custom class and I am dropping that class on a custom form.  Have not found the root problem yet.  If I make the DataSource a DataTable, it works just fine.

Comment: Does it make sense that the text in the DisplayMember needs to match the text in the DataBound Column for this to display correctly?  If the column is text, then it works.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  Are you talking about your DisplayMember for that KeyValuePair?  The DisplayMember just needs to refer to the Property name - so the KeyValuePair has two properties - "Key" and Value" and your DisplayMember would match one of them.   If you are binding to a table, then the DisplayMember instead needs to match the column's name - so if the column's name is "Stuff", the DisplayMember would be "Stuff".  Hopefully I'm following what you are asking.

Comment: What I found is that if the Column in the DataBinding is an int, but the Value from the List is a string, then I get the problem I was having.  What I did was changed the Databind to a view that displayed the text from the lookup table the int tied to.  The Key of the List would be the int from the lookup table.  If that makes any sense.  SELECT DisplayMember FROM LookupTable AS LT INNER JOIN DataTable AS DT ON LT.Id = DT.LookupId.   Then the KeyValuePair worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a `List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>` instead of a `Dictionary<int,string>`?

Anyway, I do believe your problem is located in the fact that since the binding is done against a List of KeyValuePair; the code will think that it should look for the values of DisplayMember in the List (that is, not the KeyValuePair) and finds the Value being the KeyValue and doesn't find any Key, so it does some odd parsing (READ: not sure about why you get a -1).
Think switching from `List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>` to a dictionary might just solve it.

Comment: The List would allow duplicate "key" values where the Dictionary won't.  So, one *could* have two text strings displayed with the same integer value.

Comment: I tried a Dictionary first with the following and I do not have the problem with the SelectedIndex, but the problem with the ValueMember remained the same; Dictionary<int, string> loFormat = new Dictionary<int, string> { {1, "Format 1"}, {2, "Format 2"}, {3, "Format 3"} };

Comment: @itsmatt Then I would just switch the Dictionary around, I.E have a dictionary of string, int. If this wouldn't solve my problem I would probably use a custom created object as a container. There are times where you need duplicate keys but this is rare and doesn't Tuple work then? anyway that's OT.
On Topic: Hmm what does the EventHandler look like?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall - The event handler is simple,  I added the if (this.SelectedIndex to prevent NullExceptions.          protected override void OnValidating(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                int lnCurrentValue = Convert.ToInt32(this.SelectedValue.ToString());